# PayPal Adaptive Accounts API GetVerifiedStatus Cannot determine PayPal Account status

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the current PayPal adaptive API (3.1) to verify PayPal Accounts with `GetVerifiedStatus()`. Just did the configuration as in the sample. It works with one PayPal account (result: SUCCESS), but with another account and the correct account data, I just got "Failure: Cannot determine PayPal Account status". I have to Log Level set to "FINE", but do not get any useful information.

Failure:

```
PayPal\Types\AA\GetVerifiedStatusResponse Object
(
    [responseEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\ResponseEnvelope Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2017-12-04T08:33:17.185-08:00
            [ack] => Failure
            [correlationId] => 4dd18676af93
            [build] => 36174696
        )

    [accountStatus] => 
    [countryCode] => 
    [userInfo] => 
    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorData Object
                (
                    [errorId] => 580023
                    [domain] => PLATFORM
                    [subdomain] => Application
                    [severity] => Error
                    [category] => Application
                    [message] => Cannot determine PayPal Account status
                    [exceptionId] => 
                    [parameter] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Success:

```
PayPal\Types\AA\GetVerifiedStatusResponse Object
(
    [responseEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\ResponseEnvelope Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2017-12-04T08:08:04.179-08:00
            [ack] => Success
            [correlationId] => a009f4a0b25f6
            [build] => 36174696
        )

    [accountStatus] => UNVERIFIED
    [countryCode] => 
    [userInfo] => PayPal\Types\AA\UserInfoType Object
        (
            [emailAddress] => ****
            [accountType] => ****
            [accountId] => ****
            [name] => PayPal\Types\AA\NameType Object
                (
                    [salutation] => 
                    [firstName] => ****
                    [middleName] => 
                    [lastName] => ****
                    [suffix] => 
                )

            [businessName] => 
        )

    [error] => 
)
```

Do you need more Information? What could I change?

Best!

Comment: Have you check if the email address is correct?

Comment: Yes the address is correct.